# GitHub Copilot not activation when i login

Tags: github

GitHub Copilot show this error GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed: "User not authorized"

But I have authorized on GitHub

Comment: Notice the difference between "authorized" and "authenticated". When you say "I have authorized", you probably mean that you have authenticated (i.e. logged in).

Comment: I faced to this issue. You can try my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/76437067/10206253
Hope it help

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying GitHub copilot for the first time, this error indicates that you are not part of the beta invite list. What you can do is you can join the waitlist (https://github.com/features/copilot/signup) and wait for your chance to try the beta.

If you have already got the invitation, then there was an error connecting to api.github.com to request a token to use the Copilot service.

Full Discussion: https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/7707