# IDEA plugin 'github copilot' can't login in github

Tags: authentication, intellij-plugin, github-copilot

My IDEA plugin, *GitHub copilot,* can't login in GitHub.
It is wating for GitHub Authentication...

[image]

But! My VSCode can login in successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Update your github-copilot to the latest version (1.1.24.1610) then close IDEA.
2. [Download this version of github-copilot](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/download?rel=true&updateId=172765) (1.1.20.1417) and Extract it
3. Navigate to `...\github-copilot-intellij-1.1.20.1417\github-copilot-intellij\lib`
4. Copy the `core-1.1.20` file
5. Navigate to

   - For IntelliJ IDEA

     ```
     …\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2022.1\plugins\github-copilot-intellij\lib
     ```
   - For Android Studio

     ```
     …\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2\plugins\github-copilot-intellij\lib
     ```
6. Replace `core-1.1.24` with `core-1.1.20`.

Comment: Can you share a link for the reported issue or source of the solution? It looks like this problem persists for many months.

Comment: @DawidPura use this new method https://github.com/djoxy-code/Github-copilot-Fix

Comment: The new method added by @Djoxy in the comments solved it for me!

Answer (score 13):

Also make sure u have successfully signed up with providing payment method :) (https://github.com/features/copilot) Intelij idea ignored my logins until I've configured it on GH side.

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes does this at least it happened today on PhpStorm 2023-1 EAP. Before it worked normally. I wonder if I would pay them the same way as it is working.

Comment: I wanted to try added billing account , and I cannet get signed in status in android studio is this like normal ? :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my JetBrains products.
Get to this website and activated Github copilet for my Account and it worked.
https://github.com/github-copilot/free_signup

Answer (score 1):

My issue is the same. Copilot works fine in VsCode but with IntelliJ, only the first log in when I install Github Copilot works. All following login actions failed.
My solution is to open `C:\Users\<your computer name>\AppData\Local\github-copilot\hosts.json` (replace  by your computer name) and you will see [file hosts.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9cxl.png)
Delete all data in this file and try to log in Github Copilot by IntelliJ.
You must delete this file data every time you reopen the IDE. It's manual but this is my best solution.
Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

In my case the login popup was not showing anymore on the mac - uninstalling and reinstalling the app was not working - I had to change the value `signinNotificationShown` to **false** in this file:

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/WebStorm2023.1/options/github-copilot.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

I am writing to summarize various steps I took to resolve this problem. I started from this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/35544) on same issue. All below steps are general except few places which are specific to Windows OS.

1. First of all we need to check if there is any middleman / third party authentication which we can find using this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71973332/1225413). This is specially true in organization for security and compliance reason.

   You can easily find your middleman

   a. Go to Chrome browser, open any SSL website and click on SSL certificate section.

   [image: ChromeBrowser SSL]

   b. Now click on Connection is secure and select Certificate is valid.

   [image: certificate valid]

   c. In this dialog you will see the name of SSL issuer / middleman.

   [image: SSL issuer]
2. Now that we know issuer, we can get export the particular certificate from Certificate Manager as a .DER file
   [image: Export certificate]
3. Once certificate is saved, we need to convert `.DER` into `.PEM`. We can do that by using `certutil.exe`. Use this command to convert certificate.

   `certutil.exe -encode <der file> <pem file>`
4. Now based on [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004301319-Adding-root-CA-to-intellij-on-Windows-10) add the `.PEM` file/certificate to IntelliJ IDE.

   [image: add certificate to IDE]

Answer (score 0):

remove folder and reinstall plugin in intellij
\Users\user_acc\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\plugins\github-copilot-intellij

note:

- replace **user_acc** by your user account
- replace **IntelliJIdea2022.3** by your version

Answer (score 0):

In my case caused by certificate issue.

How to know you have the same issue?

- Cancel the waiting github authentication and click on login button again.
- You will get an SSL error popup.

Fix:

- Download the root certificate of the github auth page.
- Set the env var in Windows: NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS = Cert path